# Query for multiple tables using JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, jpa

I have to make a query in criteria api of two tables that is to say I want to select in the query all the fields of the two tables.
Here I leave the models that I want to select (I have the metamodels of each of them) and I give you an example of how to select the data
      of each of them in different consultations

```
public List<Empleado> empleadoB() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Empleado> criteria = cb.createQuery(Empleado.class);
    Root<Empleado> member = criteria.from(Empleado.class);
    criteria.select(member).orderBy(cb.asc(member.get(Empleado_.p_ap)));
    return em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
}


public List<Empleado2> empleadosNom() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Empleado2> criteria = cb.createQuery(Empleado2.class);
    Root<Empleado> member = criteria.from(Empleado.class);
    Root<Tipo_docs> tDoc = criteria.from(Tipo_docs.class);
    Root<Estad_civil> eCivil = criteria.from(Estad_civil.class);
    Root<Profesiones> prof = criteria.from(Profesiones.class);
    Root<Eps> eps = criteria.from(Eps.class);
    Root<Pensiones> pens = criteria.from(Pensiones.class);
    Root<Usuario> useri = criteria.from(Usuario.class);
    Root<Cargos> cargo = criteria.from(Cargos.class);

    criteria.select(cb.construct(Empleado2.class, member.get(Empleado_.id_emp),
             member.get(Empleado_.p_ap), member.get(Empleado_.s_ap),
             member.get(Empleado_.nombre), member.get(Empleado_.tipo_doc),
             member.get(Empleado_.numero_doc), member.get(Empleado_.lugar_exp),
             member.get(Empleado_.fecha_nac), member.get(Empleado_.lugar_nac),
             member.get(Empleado_.estadocivil), member.get(Empleado_.direc),
             member.get(Empleado_.tel), member.get(Empleado_.profesion),
             cb.selectCase() .when(cb.isNull(member.get(Empleado_.matricula_prof)), "No Registrado") .otherwise(member.get(Empleado_.matricula_prof)),
             member.get(Empleado_.mail),member.get(Empleado_.eps),
             cb.selectCase() .when(cb.isNull(member.get(Empleado_.pensiones)), (long)0) .otherwise(member.get(Empleado_.pensiones)),
             cb.selectCase() .when(cb.isNull(member.get(Empleado_.usu)), "No Existe") .otherwise(member.get(Empleado_.usu)),
             tDoc.get(Tipo_docs_.desc_tdoc),
             eCivil.get(Estad_civil_.desc_ecivil), prof.get(Profesiones_.nombre_prof),
             eps.get(Eps_.nom_eps),
            cb.selectCase() .when(cb.isNull(member.get(Empleado_.pensiones)), "No Aplica") .otherwise(pens.get(Pensiones_.nom_pension)),
             cargo.get(Cargos_.id_cargo), cargo.get(Cargos_.desc_cargo) ));
    criteria.where(cb.and(cb.equal(member.get(Empleado_.tipo_doc), tDoc.get(Tipo_docs_.id_entidad)),
            cb.equal(member.get(Empleado_.estadocivil), eCivil.get(Estad_civil_.id_ecivil)),
            cb.equal(member.get(Empleado_.profesion), prof.get(Profesiones_.id_prof)),
            cb.equal(member.get(Empleado_.eps), eps.get(Eps_.id_eps)),
            cb.or(cb.equal(member.get(Empleado_.usu), useri.get(Usuario_.usuario)), cb.isNull(member.get(Empleado_.usu))),
            cb.or(cb.equal(member.get(Empleado_.pensiones), pens.get(Pensiones_.id_pension)), cb.isNull(member.get(Empleado_.pensiones))) ));
    criteria.distinct(true);


    return em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Oh, you forgot to put a "question" ...

Comment: can help me please?

Comment: You probably should read up on [joining or fetching](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-difference-join-left-join-fetch-join/) with JPA2

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: There are so many tables here. Which two do you want to join?